# How to simplify mapping between postgres data and java object / json payload (and vice versa)

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, mapping

The project is simple rest api (springboot framework) where json messages are exchanged and the payload is saved to the Postgres database.

Two methods are implemented, first (http post) to save data and second (http get) to retrieve data from the database.

Initial json request (when performing HTTP POST), payload is predefined by the client's requirements:

```
...

{
"characteristics" : [ {
    "name" : "char1",
    "value" : "value1"
  }, {
    "name" : "char2",
    "value" : "value2"
  }, {
    "name" : "char3",
    "value" : "value3"
  }
 ]
}
```

Json response (on HTTP GET) has exactly the same output as the request

```
...

{
"characteristics" : [ {
    "name" : "char1",
    "value" : "value1"
  }, {
    "name" : "char2",
    "value" : "value2"
  }, {
    "name" : "char3",
    "value" : "value3"
  }
 ]
}
```

My model looks like this:

1.

```
    public class Request {
    
    ...

    @JsonProperty("characteristics")
    private List<Characteristics> characteristics = new ArrayList<>();

    //Getters and setters

    }
```

2. 

```
    public Class Characteristics {

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String value;

    
    //Getters and setters

    }
```

regarding db communication - jpa repository was implemented and has a native query defined to retrieve data from postgres:

```
@Repository
public interface PostgresRepository extends JpaRepository<DbObject, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM someTableName", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DbObject> getAll();

}
```

Each individual characteristic "name" is a separate column in postgres:

```
        Column        |            Type             |                     
----------------------+-----------------------------+
 id                   | integer                     |
 char1                | character varying(50)       |
 char2                | character varying(50)       |
 char3                | character varying(50)       |
```

For each GET call to the REST API, the result retrival process is done as follows:

```
 ...

 
 List<DbObject> dbObjectList = postgresRepo.getAll();
 List<SpeedtestRequest> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
 SingleResult singleResult;
 
 for (DbObject dbObject : dbObjectList) {

            List<Characteristics> characteristicsList = new ArrayList<>();
            Characteristics char1 = new Characteristics("char1", dbObject.getChar1());
            characteristicsList.add(char1);
            Characteristics char2 = new Characteristics("char2", dbObject.getChar2());
            characteristicsList.add(char2);
            Characteristics char3 = new Characteristics("char3", dbObject.getChar3());
            characteristicsList.add(char3);
            
            singleResult = new SingleResult(characteristicsList)
            resultList.add(speedtestRequest);
  }


  return ResponseEntity.ok(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resultList));
```

The same process occurs and vice versa - when storing data in a database. Each characteristic must be read (parsed) and stored in a specific column in the database.

My question is - can data retrieval and this mapping of each column to a single characteristic within the Characteristics object be simplified in some way to reduce this boilerplate code?

Comment: Yes. if you are willing to change your schema. Try using `jsonb` instead. You no longer have to do any of that, as you can directly retrieve it from the Database as is (a json object).

Answer (score 0):

You can very well store your REST input as a [json or jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) document. In order to do this, you will have to change your table schema. Your table schema will ultimately look like this:

```
        Column        |            Type             |                     
----------------------+-----------------------------+
 id                   | integer                     |
 document             | jsonb                       |
```

Mind you, JSON support in Postgres starts from 9.5 and above. (9.4 / 9.3 / 9.2 are unsuported)

Comment: Unfortunately, the client has defined a table schema and it is not possible to change it.

Comment: Oh, I figured an elegant way was to store as jsonb object. May be someone will have a better way for you! Good luck